# QThread finished() emitting fails if called inside window closing

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have done an application with some threads. Everything seems to work ok if I call my `stopConsumer` inside a keypressedEvent. But If I call it inside a destructor of closeEvent.. it fails.

My QThread class that has a run method like this one:

```
void Consumer::run()
{
    forever {

        // do something something
        // do something something
        // do something something


        //-------------------------------- check for abort
        abortMutex.lock();
        if(abort) {
            abortMutex.unlock();
            qDebug() << "abort..";
            break;
        } abortMutex.unlock();
        //-------------------------------- check for abort
    }
    qDebug() << "Consumer > emit finished()";
    emit finished();
}

void Consumer::stopConsume() {
    abortMutex.lock();
    abort = true;
    abortMutex.unlock();
}
```

and a method in the MainWindow:

```
void initConsumers()
{
    consumer1 = new Consumer(....);

    connect(consumer1, SIGNAL(finished()),
            this, SLOT(deleteConsumer()));

    consumer1->start();
}

void stopConsumer() {
    if(consumer1!=NULL) {
        qDebug() << "stopConsumer";
        consumer1->stopConsume();
    }
}
```

If I have a keypressed that calls `stopConsumer`.. it's ok, `deleteConsumer` is reached.

If I call `stopConsumer` inside the MainWindow destructor or inside a MainWindow `closeEvent`.. the slot `deleteConsumer` is never reached!

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you keep the app event loop running after closing the main window? If you quit event loop (quit on main window close), pending queued signals will not be processed.

Comment: yes i think this is the problem, how to avoid the event loop to be finished?

Comment: Well, you can set the main window not to quit the app on close. Instead you wait for finished() signal from your thread object and quit the app in slot connected to this signal (deleteConsumer slot in your case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the `Consumer` class and your `MainWindow` have different [thread affinities](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/threads-qobject.html), the call you make to `connect` inside `initConsumers()` is likely using a [`Qt::QueuedConnection`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), which means that the `deleteConsumer()` slot won't get called immediately.

If you would like to ensure that the consumer gets deleted from the destructor of your main window (or equivalently, from a close event), one possible solution is to call `stopConsume()` on the consumer, then wait until the thread is no longer running (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qthread.html#isRunning), then call `deleteConsumer()` directly.

**Update**

Here's an example of what I described above:

```
consumer1->stopConsume();
consumer1->wait();
deleteConsumer();
```

It's not advisable to switch the connection type to `Qt:DirectConnection` since that will cause the `deleteConsumer()` function to be called from the body of `Consumer::run()`, which will likely crash your application.

Comment: how to wait until the thread is no longer running? and what's if I change the connection type?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem here is that you're deriving from QThread, which is not how it is supposed to be used. You can read about why deriving from QThread is wrong [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Instead, what you should be doing is deriving your class from QObject, creating a QThread object and moving the derived QObject instance to that thread.

```
class Consumer : public QObject
{
    ...

    signals:
        void finished();

    private slots:
        void run();
}

QThread pThread = new QThread;
Consumer pObject = new Consumer;

// move the pObject to the thread
pObject->moveToThread(pThread);
```

You can then control the thread with signals and slots.

```
// assuming you've added a run slot function to the Consumer class
connect(pThread, SIGNAL(started()), pObject, SLOT(run()));
connect(pObject, SIGNAL(finished()), pThread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(pObject, SIGNAL(finished()), pObject, SLOT(deleteLater()));

// Note the thread cleans itself up here, but if the app is quitting,
// waiting on the thread to finish may be required instead
connect(pThread, SIGNAL(finished()), pThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

And start the thread: -

```
pThread->start();
```

Used this way, it also enables multiple objects to be moved to a single new thread, rather than creating a new thread per object instance.

Comment: I know that article but I don't think this is the real problem. I'm already controlling the thread with signal/slot.. the problem is that this signal/slot control mechanism is failing if I stop the thread inside a closing the main window. I think R.A. answer and Archie comments are showing me why: the problem is that inside the closeEvent/destructor of the MainWindow there is no more the Qt main event loop running and my signal/slot mechanism is no more working

Comment: If you know the article, why do you continue to inherit from QThread? Anyhow, you're emitting finished from the run() function and the docs state "Returning from this method will end the execution of the thread", which I assume would also emit finished(); is that what you want? Also The purpose of the protected run() function is to allow an inherited class "to facilitate advanced thread management", which is not what you're doing here. I still maintain that using it as designed is going to be better and may just fix the issue. Of-course, it's up to you what you do; I'm only trying to help.

Comment: In addition, if you look at the code for QThread, you'll see that the run function simply calls exec(), which sets up the event loop. Qt docs state for finished() that the event loop has finished executing, which is not the case when you emit finished from your run() function.

Comment: yess, thank you very much for the help. And you're right, a lot of times improve the design resolve some errors. Even if I don't think this is the problem I'll try! Thanks!

Comment: This article is also very useful and explains other problems and things to avoid, such as allocating heap objects in the constructor of your object: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/ Look carefully at the connections at the bottom of the article and the description of how they're used to cleanup the thread.